# Sudoku solver backtracking in javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, sudoku, backtracking

I'm trying to work up a Sudoku solver in JavaScript using backtracking, I've made some research, seen similar problems, but my method is different; and it's not working.

Here's the JavaScript code:

```
var grid = [ // Empty grid to test the solver
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
           ];
var invalid = [ // Here go additional invalid numbers
               [[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]],
               [[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]],
               [[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]],
               [[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]],
               [[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]],
               [[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]],
               [[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]],
               [[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]],
               [[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]],
              ];

function sudokuSolver() { // The solver function
    for (var r = 0; r < 9; r++) { // For each row
        for (var c = 0; c < 9; c++) { // For each column
            for (var n = 1; n < 11; n++) { // For each number + 10
                if (n == 10) { // If no solutions were found for the current cell, backtrack.
                    if (c == 0) { // If at left-most position
                        var x = grid[--r][8]; // Assign the number in the previous cell to "x". Decremented "r" because the previous cell is in the previous row, and the number in it should be changed
                        invalid[r+1][0] = []; // Reset invalid numbers for current cell
                        invalid[r][8].push(x); // Mark "x" as invalid in the previous cell
                        c = 7; // The number in the previous cell should be changed, the previous cell is in column 8, the loop increments each time the code block is executed, so c here should hold 8 - 1 = 7
                    } else { // Same goal here
                        var x = grid[r][--c]; 
                        invalid[r][c+1] = [];
                        invalid[r][c].push(x);
                        c--;
                    }
                    break;
                } else if (isValid(r, c, n)) {
                    grid[r][c] = n; // If n is valid, put it
                    console.log(r + ',' + c + ',' + n);
                    break; // And break the loop (it won't reach n = 10)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Print the solution
    for (var r = 0; r < 9; r++) {
        for (var c = 0; c < 9; c++) {
            document.getElementById('sudoku').getElementsByTagName('tr')[r].getElementsByTagName('td')[c].innerHTML = grid[r][c];
        }
    }
}

function isValid(r,c,n) {
    var a;
    var b = true;
    var col = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        col += grid[i][c];
    }
    var sec = '';
    for (var lr = 3 * Math.floor(r / 3); lr < 3 * Math.floor(r / 3) + 3; lr++) {
        for (var lc = 3 * Math.floor(c / 3); lc < 3 * Math.floor(c / 3) + 3; lc++) {
            sec += grid[lr][lc];
        }
    }
    a = (grid[r].toString().indexOf(n) == -1 && col.indexOf(n) == -1 && sec.indexOf(n) == -1);
    for (var i = 0; i < invalid[r][c].length; i++) {
        if (n == invalid[r][c][i]) b = false; break;
    }
    return (a && b);
}
```

Without `if (n == 10) { // Code }` It does what's expected.

With it, the browser stops responding then asks whether to stop the script.

In the console I get:

`1,5,7
1,6,3
1,5,7
1,6,3
...`

Any clues on what's wrong?

This is the idea:

(I) Try "1" in the current cell, if it's valid, put it in the grid array and proceed to next cell, otherwise, try "2" and check again, then "3" if "2" is invalid, etc... if a valid number is found, put it in the grid and proceed to next cell, if there's no valid number (reaches 10), clear invalid numbers for current cell (if any), mark the number in the previous cell as invalid there (doesn't lead to a solution), and go there (backtrack).

(II) Repeat (I) until the Sudoku is solved.

---

#### Problem fixed.

```
if (n == invalid[r][c][i]) b = false; break;
```

was meant to be:

```
if (n == invalid[r][c][i]) {b = false; break;}
```

Comment: Don't mutate `r` or `c` within the loops. Your probably facing a situation where the mutations inside the for loop are causing the values to never reach the condition that lets the loop end. Hence the infinite loop and the resulting _browser stops responding then asks whether to stop the script_

Comment: P.S. I stopped looking at the code example. The indenting is so bad my head started to hurt.

Comment: I don't really have time to try to understand the code.  In the else clause you decrement "c" twice.  Did you mean to?

Comment: @James, yes, I meant to. I want "c" to hold the previous value the next time in the loop, and since the loop increments by 1, I had to decrement it by 1 twice. (backtracking)

Comment: @Sukima, The indenting has been updated.

Comment: what if (c==1) and then is decremented twice.

Comment: @James, it has to be (c==0) because the leftmost position is at 0, since array indexes start with 0.

Comment: Problem solved! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have an infinite loop

```
for (var c = 0; c < 9; c++) {…}
```

The only way to exit the loop is to have `c >= 9`. Normally this would happen when the `c++` eventually increments it. However, when `n == 10` your logic will always perform a decrement of some sort (`--c`, `c--`, and `c = 7`) to prevent `c` from ever reaching `9`.

Therefore when the `n == 10` code branch is introduced the decrementing of `c` happens once for every iteration of the for loop that manages `c` Since the decrementing is either `c = 7` or `c = c - 2` it will not reach `9` and end the loop.

The answer is to not mutate the values inside the loop. Refactor the code to manage `r`, `c`, and `n` as if they were immutable within the for loop block. Then perform calculations on those values in the block to find the values you need to perform your business logic. Perhaps making intermediate variables to store intermediate values.

Another big help would be to break out each part of the logic into functions. Doing so would help you abstract the complexity in such a way as to help you *wrap your head around* and since they are functions they can be deterministic. Meaning what you put in will result in a predictable output. Then it is only a matter of composing the functions in the order and want to perform the business logic.

Comment: The loop that manages `n` will reach `n = 10` only if there is no valid number for the current cell; otherwise, it breaks.
I'll try using more functions, if I don't make it this way.